# How can I use react masonry with react-infinite-scroller?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, infinite-scroll

I have a list of images that will be infinately scrolled and when I hit the bottom of the page, load more.

I have used this component: https://github.com/CassetteRocks/react-infinite-scroller

It works great for an array of images.

For the next step I want to make a grid of images with some text under it. Hence, the heights of the boxes will be variable. Also, it would be great to have a grid so I can put more than one box on a row.

How can I use react masonry (https://github.com/eiriklv/react-masonry-component) or (https://react.rocks/example/react-infinite-grid) for this purpose?
Does react-infinite-grid handle variable height blocks?

Here is a code snippet of what I have now:

```
        <InfiniteScroll
            pageStart={0}
            loadMore={this.props.onInfiniteLoad}
            hasMore={this.props.hasNextPage}
            loader={<div>{'Loading ...'}</div>}>
            {this.getSearchResultList()}
        </InfiniteScroll>
```

Comment: have you figured it out???

Answer (score 1):

Now, I think we can do that by this.
(https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-masonry-infinite)

[Demo page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7XFF.gif)

**1. Install**

```
npm install --save react-masonry-infinite
```

**2. Using**

```
import MasonryInfiniteScroller from 'react-masonry-infinite';

...
        <MasonryInfiniteScroller
            pageStart={0}
            loadMore={this.props.onInfiniteLoad}
            hasMore={this.props.hasNextPage}
            loader={<div>{'Loading ...'}</div>}>
            {this.getSearchResultList()}
        </MasonryInfiniteScroller>
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26312718)

Comment: @JasonAller Thank you for the feedback. I edit the answer.